# Scanning user input text

Tags: java, string, text, user-input

I´ve been trying to get user input as a text and then outputting one of 2 answers depending on the input. This is how far I´ve managed to get with the help of Google:

```
import java.util.*;
public class kt_3_1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String t;
    System.out.println("Enter the time of year");
    t = scanner.nextLine();
    if ( t.equals("summer") ) {
        System.out.printf("%n%s", t);
    }   else {
    System.out.println("FUUUUUUUu");
    }
}

}
```

This program compiles but always returns "FUUUUUUUu", even if I´d typed "summer". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the variable `vaheaeg` defined?

Comment: should be t.equals("summer")

Comment: user input is scanned into `t`, and you compare `varheaeg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program would not even compile as vaheaeg is not defined as variable anywhere in program. Try using this program it works for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kt_3_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String t;
        System.out.println("Enter the time of year");
        t = scanner.nextLine();
        if ( t.equals("summer") ) {
            System.out.printf("%n%s", t);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("FUUUUUUUu");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, and I´m sorry I forgot to change 1 variable. The program now works. From what I understand, even though my original program was written correctly, it probably didn´t work because I´d saved it in UTF-8.